# Not being able to catch an exception

Tags: python, exception, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So I am trying to catch the Webdriver exception and don't want its traceback to pollute my logs. Here is the bit of code

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException, WebDriverException

try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.loading')))
except TimeoutException:
    log.msg("Seneium Timeout: {}".format(response.url))
except WebDriverException as e:
    log.msg("Selenium Exception: {0} Message: {1}".format("my message", str(e)))
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

yet I'm still getting these:

```
 <full traceback here>
 selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to GhostDriver
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the exception is occurring within the `try` block?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The exception is raised outside of your `try/except` block while initializing a `WebDriver` instance:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
```

---

FYI, this happens while starting `PhantomJS` with `GhostDriver`, quote from the [source code](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/py/selenium/webdriver/phantomjs/service.py#61):

```
def start(self):
    """
    Starts PhantomJS with GhostDriver.

    :Exceptions:
     - WebDriverException : Raised either when it can't start the service
       or when it can't connect to the service
    """
    try:
        self.process = subprocess.Popen(self.service_args, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                                        close_fds=platform.system() != 'Windows',
                                        stdout=self._log, stderr=self._log)

    except Exception as e:
        raise WebDriverException("Unable to start phantomjs with ghostdriver.", e)
    count = 0
    while not utils.is_connectable(self.port):
        count += 1
        time.sleep(1)
        if count == 30:
             raise WebDriverException("Can not connect to GhostDriver")
```

And, `start()` is [called in `WebDriver`'s constructor (`__init__()` method)](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/py/selenium/webdriver/phantomjs/webdriver.py#50).

In other words, it starts a service, but cannot connect to it.

Comment: most probably while driver.get(url) but you're right. thanks.

Comment: @yayu updated the answer with links to the source code. It is happening on webdriver's initialization step. Thanks for motivating me to look into sources :)

Comment: you're the inspiration here :)

Answer (score 0):

you could try - ElementClickInterceptedException